# spring-boot RedisTemplate<String,User> exception

Tags: redis, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

My code like this:

**Java:**

```
@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String,User> myTemplate;

@Override
public String login(String email, String password) {
    User user = this.userRepository.findByEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    System.out.println(user);

    if (user == null)  return null;

    String key1 = "lic" + "$" + user.getId() + "$" + user.getRole() + "$" + user.getName() + "$" + user.getEmail();

    ValueOperations<String, User> ops = this.myTemplate.opsForValue();

    if (!this.myTemplate.hasKey(key1)) {
        ops.set(key1, user);
    }
    return key1;
}
```

when app run, inject bean ,like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationApp extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


//    @Autowired
//    private RedisTemplate<String,String> template;

@Bean
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    return new JedisConnectionFactory();
}

@Bean
RedisTemplate<String, User> redisTemplate() {
    final RedisTemplate<String, User> template = new RedisTemplate<String, User>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<User>(User.class));
    template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<User>(User.class));
    return template;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    // super.addInterceptors(registry);
    registry.addInterceptor(new AuthorAccess()).addPathPatterns("/api/sc/**");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(ApplicationApp.class, args);
}
}
```

then , call login service found error like this:

org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type com.qycloud.oatos.license.domain.User to type java.lang.String

Comment: try using template.convertAndSend

Answer (score 4):

Set ValueSerializer with Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer instead of GenericToStringSerializer and it should work. GenericToStringSerializer do not support Object to String conversion.

```
template.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<User>(User.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register you're own implementation of `TypeConverter` or a `ConversionService` able to deal with `User.class` via eg. `setTypeConverter(TypeConverter converter)`. Otherwise `GenericToStringSerializer` will just try using the `DefaultConversionService` which does not know about your type.